# Is it possible to rotate a ScrollView programmatically in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, orientation, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I have an activity in which I have a camera preview.

I want `noSensor|landscape` orientation fixed for the activity so that the camera preview works with out any jerk during the orientation changes.

Now I don't get the orientation feedback from the Android which is good for the preview.

But I have some UI that has to respond to all 4 orientations.

The layout xml file is in portrait.

I listen to the sensor orientation changes in `onOrientationChanged`,I get the views by Id and move around the controls to simulate the orientation changes for the UI.

Now I face the problem particularly in displaying the scroll view with thumbnails of captured images.

The `scrollview` should be displayed horizontal always at the bottom of the view.

The idea is the activity will display the UI always in the portrait mode(as the layout it uses).

I have to rotate the ui controls to simulate the orientation changes.

I have a `linearLayout` container to which I add the ImageViews dynamically.

When I am in portrait mode I set the container's orientation to horizontal and add the linear container to a horizontal scrollview so that it scrolls horizontally.

when I have to simulate the landscape orientation I change the orientation of the linear container to vertical , remove it from the horizontal view and add  the container to a scrollView so that it scrolls vertically.

This approach works fine for portrait and landscape but during the reverse landscape  and reverse portrait modes, the scrollview should display elements from bottom to top and the horizontal scrollview should display from right to left as shown in the diagrams below.

I have changed the alignment of the container which is doing the job but the scrollview  scrolling lint is fixed to the bottom.

I want to scroll downwards during landscape mode(with the first image on the top and last image in the bottom) and scroll up during the landscape reverse(with the first image at the bottom and the last image in the top).

I need a way to reverse the limits of the scrolling for the reverse modes(Landscape rev and portrait rev).

Please help.

Below is the UI spec for what I want to achieve. All views are simulated in the portrait mode:
[image: Portrait][image: Portrait reverse][image: Landscape][image: Landscape reverse]